# Поиск в словарях python

Tags: python, словари

Есть два словаря необходимо выявить совпадения id в первом словаре со вторым при совпадении отображать name второго словаря, как можно сделать? Пробую циклами пока тщетно.

```
dic1 = {'id':'123','name':'Case'}{'id':'1234','name':'Case2'}
dic2 = {'id':'123','name':'Name1'}{'id':'456','name':'Name2'}
for i in dic1:
    for j in dic2:
        if i[id] == j[id]:
            print(j[name])
```

Comment: У вас словари не словари. Не верный формат и python выкинет `Syntax error`. Приведите корректные входные данные. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1382934/edit) под самим вопросом и внесите изменения

Comment: Словарь не может содержать одинаковые ключи

Comment: @АлексейБелкин одинаковые ключи не вызовут синтаксической ошибки. А вот пробельные символы между сущностями - легко

Comment: @Dmitry, одинаковые ключи == потеря данных

Comment: @АлексейБелкин никто и не спорит. Но одинановые ключи == перезапись значения и никакой ошибки вы не увидите

Comment: спасибо что поправили, отредактировал сообщение, данные приходят с mongodb и в одной переменной несколько словарей если я правильно понял поправьте если ошибаюсь

Comment: Пусть лучше ошибка, т.к. сразу можно увидеть что и где, чем потерять и потом искать где потеря произошла

Comment: @hello_v а вы сами пробуете запускать тот код который вы пишите? После внесения правки ситуация не изменилась. Вы вот это подразумеваете `[{'id':'123','name':'Case'},{'id':'1234','name':'Case2'}]`? Можете получить данные, закинуть в переменную и вывести `print(переменная)`. Возможны вы список словарей получаете или вообще строку с таким форматом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, после длительных дискуссий, посмотрите (накидал на коленке - без оптимизации):

```
lst_dic1 = [{'id': '123', 'name': 'Case1'},
            {'id': '1234', 'name': 'Case2'},
            {'id': '12345', 'name': 'Case3'}]

lst_dic2 = [{'id': '123', 'name': 'Name1'},
            {'id': '1234', 'name': 'Name2'},
            {'id': '4567', 'name': 'Name3'},
            {'id': '89010', 'name': 'Name4'}]

for elementDict1 in lst_dic1:
    for elementDict2 in lst_dic2:
        if elementDict1['id'] == elementDict2['id']:
            print(elementDict2['name'])
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо большое так работает, странно что не работает с данными которые поступают из mongodb, попробую сформулировать более подробно в новом вопросе.

Comment: Может, там структура данных по другому сформирована.